# Mongo db security

Tags: security, mongodb, code-injection

Hi i was wondering which are the main things to pay attention when saving data in mongo db?

I mean is there any kind of injection attack possible to the mongo db? 
Anything like SQL injections?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anytime you pass an unprotected string to something which parses it, you're vulnerable. XSS, SQL injection, buffer overflows -- they all have different names, but they're all input validation problems where input data turns into executable code.

Sanitize your input; pass references and bind variables.